# VBA vlookup previous cell with generic code

Tags: vba, vlookup

I need to set up a vlookup loop in VBA.
I've got it to work for the first row but I need the lookup cell to be generic. Right now B3 is looking up A3, but when it loops B4 is also looking up A3 when I need it to look up A4.

Does anyone know a way to look up the previous selected cell instead of a set range?

this is my code so far:

```
 Range("A3").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = " "
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("test").Range("A3"), Sheets("HD Extract").Range("Extract"), 4, False)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("test").Range("B3"), Sheets("HD Extract").Range("Wordings"), 2, False)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("test").Range("C3"), Sheets("HD Extract").Range("PriorityRank"), 3, False)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("test").Range("C3"), Sheets("HD Extract").Range("Wordings"), 5, False)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Select
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below - it is a very generic  one. It will require modifications (your vlookup column has to be adjusted together with your vlookup range), but general principle holds.

```
lastrow = Cells(Activesheet.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
For r = 3 to lastrow
    For c = 2 to 5
        Cells(r,c).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Sheets("test").Range(Cells(r,c-1), Sheets("HD Extract").Range("Extract"), 4,False)
        If Cells(r,c).Value = " " Then GoTo nextstep
    Next r
Next c
Nextstep:
```

Comment: the "LastRow =" line is giving me a "Compile error: Variable not defined" message - am I missing something?

Comment: @MaryKateWyatt If you use Option Explicit, then you have to declare it wiht `Dim lastrow as Long`. And you would have to adjust how you vlookup data based on the loop.